# Why my counter doesn't work in "uber-go/tally"?

Tags: go, prometheus

Can you please help me to find out why my event counters don't get reported. I even put the debugger on the reporter and it is not triggering. Time recorder triggers fine though.

Here is the implementation.

I have a Kafka consumer which I have defined the followings: (consumer.go)

```
reporter := metrics.NewPrintStatsReporter()
    // Report every 100*time.Millisecond
    rootScope, closer := tally.NewRootScope(tally.ScopeOptions{
        Reporter: reporter,
    }, time.Second)
    defer func(closer io.Closer) {
        err := closer.Close()
        if err != nil { 
          ...
        }
    }(closer)
    subScope := rootScope.SubScope("Events")
```

then I do:

```
supportedEventCount := subScope.Counter(metrics.SupportedEventTypes)
unSupportedEventCount := subScope.Counter(metrics.UnsupportedEventTypes)
totalEventTypes := subScope.Counter(metrics.TotalEventTypes)
kafkaReadLatency := rootScope.Timer(metrics.KafkaReadLatency)
```

in the same file

```
go func() {
        defer close(messages)
        for { ...

            st := time.Now()
            m, err := c.r.ReadMessage(ctx)
            kafkaConsumerReadLatency := time.Since(st)
            if kafkaConsumerReadLatency < 5*time.Minute {
                kafkaReadLatency.Record(kafkaConsumerReadLatency)
            }

            // Reporting any kind of event
            totalEventTypes.Inc(1)
            if helpers.IsSupportedEvent(logger, &kafkaEvent) {
                        supportedEventCount.Inc(1)
                        messages <- kafkaEvent
            } else {
                        unSupportedEventCount.Inc(1)
            }
}()
...
```

`kafkaReadLatency.Record(kafkaConsumerReadLatency)` works fine I get `timer kafka_read_latency 34.479058541s`

However non of the counters are working... which is very strange.

Here is my tally interface reporter: (very standard, 100% matches the supplied example)

```
package metrics

import (
    "fmt"
    tally "github.com/uber-go/tally/v4"
    "time"
)

const (
    SupportedEventTypes   = "supported_event_types"
    UnsupportedEventTypes = "unsupported_event_types"
    TotalEventTypes       = "total_event_types"
    KafkaReadLatency      = "kafka_read_latency"
)

type printStatsReporter struct{}

func NewPrintStatsReporter() tally.StatsReporter {
    return &printStatsReporter{}
}

func (r *printStatsReporter) ReportCounter(name string, _ map[string]string, value int64) {
    fmt.Printf("count %s %d\n", name, value)
}

func (r *printStatsReporter) ReportGauge(name string, _ map[string]string, value float64) {
    fmt.Printf("gauge %s %f\n", name, value)
}

func (r *printStatsReporter) ReportTimer(name string, _ map[string]string, interval time.Duration) {
    fmt.Printf("timer %s %s\n", name, interval.String())
}

...

func (r *printStatsReporter) Capabilities() tally.Capabilities {
    return r
}

func (r *printStatsReporter) Reporting() bool {
    return true
}

func (r *printStatsReporter) Tagging() bool {
    return true
}

func (r *printStatsReporter) Flush() {
    fmt.Printf("flush\n")
}
```

Here is the example:
https://github.com/uber-go/tally/blob/master/example/main.go